# How do I fix this mess? (Edges, Vertices merging after Ctrl+J)

Tags: objects

I messed up.
How do I fix this mess? (This happened after merging 8 objects Ctrl+J)
My whole model has a horrible looking line down the middle of it. Including the face (ow).

As you can see there are many problems. 
I can't ctrl+z because the program has been closed since. Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: my horror stories with Ctrl+J always result from not applying Modifiers before the join or the Mesh Auto smooth angle. Can you undo the join, apply the modifiers plus other per mesh settings and then rejoin?

Comment: It looks like you mirrored half of a human and merged it, but the vertices were not all on the same Z-Axis so some of them were merged and others not. You could select the edgeloop and then scale it to 0 (in Y-Axis probably). The merging will probably be more successful then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you go to *Edit* mode, press <kbd>P</kbd> and select *By loose parts*. This will seperate the meshes. Or just select the faces of the meshes you want to seperate and then press <kbd>P</kbd> and then select *By selection*. This will seperate the selected region.